# Max and Min group by 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have the following table that shows me every time a car has his tank filled. It returns the date, the car id, the mileage it had at that time and the liters filled:

```
|   Date     | Vehicle_ID | Mileage | Liters |
| 2016-10-20 | 234        | 123456  | 100    |
| 2016-10-20 | 345        | 458456  | 215    |
| 2016-10-20 | 323        | 756456  | 265    |
| 2016-10-25 | 234        | 123800  | 32     |
| 2016-10-26 | 345        | 459000  | 15     |
| 2016-10-26 | 323        | 756796  | 46     |
```

The idea is to calculate the average comsumption by month (I can't do it by day because not every car fills the tank every day).

To get that, i tried to get max(mileage)-min(mileage)/sum(liters) group by month. But this will only work for 1 specific car and 1 specific month.

If I try for 1 specific car and several months, the max and min will not return properly. If I add all the cars, even worse, as it will assume the max and min as if every car was the same.

```
select convert(char(7), Date, 127) as year_month,
       sum("Liters tanked")/(max("Mileage")-min("Mileage"))*100 as Litres_per_100KM
from Tanking
where convert(varchar(10),"Date",23) >= DATEADD(mm, -5, GETDATE()) 
group by convert(char(7), Date, 127)
```

This will not work as it will assume the max and min from all the cars.

The "workflow" shoud be this:
- For each month, get the max and min mileage for each car. Calculate max-min to get the mileage it rode that month. Sum the mileage for each car to get a total mileage driven by all the cars. Sum the liters tanked. Divide the total liters by the total mileage.

How can I get the result:

```
| YearMonth | Average |
| 2016-06   |  30     |
| 2016-07   | 32      |
| 2016-08   | 46      |
| 2016-09   | 34      |
```

Comment: "I can't do it by day because not every car fills the tank every day". Isn't daily consumption just monthly consumption divided by roughly 30?

Comment: Hi Strawberry. No. If I wanted "average by Day" it would work like that. But what i meant by daily was "day 1 - average of X", "Day 2 - average of Y", etc.

Comment: The output includes rows for `2016-09`, `2016-08`, `2016-07` and `2016-06`.  But the sample data does not include records for these months.  Can  you update so we have something to work against.

Comment: You're going to need two queries overall. You'll need to group by the month, year and vehicle to get each vehicle's min/max mileage and fuel consumption. Once you know the mileage per each vehicle per each month, you can then calculate total mileage / total fuel per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more complicated problem than it seems.  The problem is that you don't want to lose miles between months.  It is tempting to do something like this:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       sum(liters) / (max(mileage) - min(mileage))
from Tanking
where Date >= dateadd(month, -5, getdate()) 
group by year(date), month(date);
```

However, this misses miles and liters that *span* month boundaries.  In addition, the liters on the first record of the month are for the *previous* milage difference.  Oops!  That is not correct.

One way to fix this is to look up the next values.  The query looks something like this:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       sum(next_liters) / (max(next_mileage) - min(mileage))
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by vehicle_id order by date) as next_date,
             lead(mileage) over (partition by vehicle_id order by date) as next_mileage,
             lead(liters) over (partition by vehicle_id order by date) as next_liters
      from Tanking t
     ) t
where Date >= dateadd(month, -5, getdate()) 
group by year(date), month(date);
```

These queries use simplified column names, so escape characters don't interfere with the logic.

EDIT:

Oh, you have multiple cars (probably what `vehicle_Id` is there for).  You want two levels of aggregation.  The first query would look like:

```
select yyyy, mm, sum(liters) as liters, sum(mileage_diff) as mileage_diff,
       sum(mileage_diff) / sum(liters) as mileage_per_liter
from (select vehicle_id, year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm,
             sum(liters) as liters,
             (max(mileage) - min(mileage)) as mileage_diff
      from Tanking
      where Date >= dateadd(month, -5, getdate()) 
      group by vehicle_year(date), month(date)
     ) t
group by yyyy, mm;
```

Similar changes to the second query (with `vehicle_id` in the `partition by` clauses) would work for the second version.

Comment: thanks for the answer.Assuming we want an approximation (as it is not possible to understand the mileage and liters that span across months). The first query would not work because let's imagine there are 30 cars. The max mileage could be from car 1, which has 500k miles on the odometer, and the min could be from car 21 which has 10 miles. Even if every car only rode 10 miles this month the total mileage should be 300 miles. But the max(mileage)-min(mileage) would return 500k - 10miles.. That's my problem - How can i get the difference between the max and min for each car and then sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the sums per car per month in a subquery. Then calculate the average per month in an outer query using the values of the subquery:

```
select year_month,
       (1.0*sum(liters_per_car)/sum(mileage_per_car))*100.0 as Litres_per_100KM
from (
   select convert(char(7), [Date], 127) as year_month,       
          sum(Liters) as liters_per_car,
          max(Mileage)-min(Mileage) as mileage_per_car       
   from Tanking
   group by convert(char(7), [Date], 127), Vehicle_ID) as t
group by year_month
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to get dif(mileage) and then calculate consumption:

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/OKZO55169

```
with cte (car, datec, difm, liters)
as 
(
select 
    car, 
    datec, 
    mileage - lag(mileage,1,mileage) over(partition by car order by car, mileage) as difm, 
    liters 
from #consum 
) 
select 
    car, 
    year(datec) as [year], 
    month(datec) as [month], 
    ((cast(sum(liters) as float)/cast(sum(difm) as float)) * 100.0) as [l_100km]
from 
    cte
group by 
    car, year(datec), month(datec)
```